# Issue with android development kit

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I installed the ADK (android development kit) in eclipse. The install went perfect for me. 
When I try to set the SDK path I get the following message:

Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (1182).

I installed the adk 5 times already, and installed it again with the same result.

Previously I installed an older ADK version, but Eclipse told me to update my ADK to develop for android 4.1.

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: you said that you installed 5 times, but did you actually downloaded it 5 times or just used the same file(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your Eclipse installation contain the necessary parts of the JDT (for Java editing) and WST (for XML editing)? I guess so from your update story, but just making sure.

Are you on a 64 bit version of Windows or are you on Linux and use a non Sun JRE? In both cases you might run into trouble with the keystore that is used by the ADT. You might want to try a 32 bit JRE on Windows or the Sun6 JRE on Linux.

Besides that, could you please open the error log view, search the entry with the error message from your posting and double click it. It should then show a stack trace indicating what went wrong in the Eclipse code in more detail. If you have more error entries with the same time stamp (+/- 1 second) directly below or above that one, those might also be interesting.

Last thing: Are you sure that Eclipse itself is executed on a reasonable new Java version? (Some older version of the ADT broke if run on Java 1.4). You can check this in the About dialog.